# Error: 'Program.Coefficient()': not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#

I don't want the `else` statement to return a value, but just *run the method again*. However, I get **compile time error**

> 'Program.Coefficient()': not all code paths return a value.

How do I get rid of this error?

This is the code:

```
public static double Coefficient()
{
    string string1 = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] stringArray = string1.Split('^');

    double[] doubleArray = new double[stringArray.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.Length; i++)
    {
        doubleArray[i] = Double.Parse(stringArray[i]);
    }

    if (doubleArray.Length == 2)
    {
        double coefficient = Math.Pow(doubleArray[0], doubleArray[1]);
        return coefficient;
    }

    else if (doubleArray.Length == 1)
    {
        double coefficient = doubleArray[0];
        return coefficient;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please follow the specified input form (a^b).");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Coefficient();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error means that at least one flow possibility does not return a value, which is the last 'else' in your case.

The last line should be then:

```
return Coefficient();
```

Comment: Will this just run the method again?

Comment: Recursive call and stackoverflowexception after enough time?

Comment: @Anders: Yes, and return the value of that run (this is a recursive call).

Comment: @Metheny I'm new to programming so sorry for the many questions, but how does it return a value of the run when there is nothing to return? I just want it to run the method again until a value is returned through the 'if' or 'else if' statement.

Comment: The original method execution will call the same method (this is called a recursive call). In the second (inner, recursive) execution, in case the user enters a different value, that the condition will allow the 'if' to be evaluated as 'true'. and a return value will be returned to the original method execution which will in turn return the value.

Answer (score 2):

As your function returns value, that means from each if..else block you need to `return double value`.

*Here you are not returning any value from else block. You need to return double value from else block*

```
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please follow the specified input form (a^b).");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return Coefficient();  // This will call recursively  same function. for recursion use return Coefficient() ;
             //return 0; //If you don't want recursion, then comment above line and return 0

        }
```

---

I would prefer to refactor your code to minimize code present in `Coefficient()` method. something like ,

```
   public static double Coefficient()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string string1 = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] stringArray = string1.Split('^');
            double[] doubleArray = Array.ConvertAll(stringArray, double.Parse);


            if (doubleArray.Length == 2)
            {
                double coefficient = Math.Pow(doubleArray[0], doubleArray[1]);
                return coefficient;
            }

            else if (doubleArray.Length == 1)
            {
                return doubleArray[0];
            }
          Console.WriteLine("Please follow the specified input form (a^b).");
        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't want the 'else' to return a value, I just want it to run the method again until a value is returned through the 'if' or 'else if' statement.

Comment: Updated my answer, please check

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to *redesign* the routine (I can't see any need in *recursion*). You can implement a *loop* in order to keep asking until user inputs (`Console.ReadLine()`) valid value:

```
public static double Coefficient() {
  while (true) {
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    string[] items = input.Split('^');

    if (items.Length == 1) {
      if (double.TryParse(items[0], out double A))
        return A; // One valid value 
    }
    else if (items.Length == 2) {
      if (double.TryParse(items[0], out double A) && 
          double.TryParse(items[1], out double B))
        return Math.Pow(A, B); // Two valid values
    } 

    // Neither one valid value, nor two valid values pattern 
    Console.WriteLine("Please follow the specified input form (a^b)."); 
    // No need in "Console.ReadKey();" - the routine will stop on Console.ReadLine()
  }          
}
```

Be careful with `Double.Parse` since it *throws exception* on invalid string (e.g. if user inputs `"bla-bla-bla"`); use `Double.TryParse` instead.